# unix awk column equal to a variable

Tags: bash, variables, unix, awk, while-loop

I want to print the lines that with two columns equal to a variable, for example, input:

```
2607s1  NC_000067.6 95.92   49  1   1   3   50  1e-14   84.2
2607s1  NC_000067.6 97.73   44  1   0   7   50  4e-14   84.2
2607s1  NC_000067.6 97.67   43  1   0   8   50  1e-13   75.0
```

and variables for first and last column:

```
a="2607s1"; b="84.2"
```

and using awk command, output:

```
2607s1  NC_000067.6 95.92   49  1   1   3   50  1e-14   84.2
2607s1  NC_000067.6 97.73   44  1   0   7   50  4e-14   84.2
```

I have tried the following but not work:

```
awk -v '$1==$a' && '$10==$b' test_file
cat test_file|awk '$1=="($a)" && $10=="($b)"'
cat test_file|awk '$1==($a) && $10==($b)'
cat test_file|awk '$1=="$a" && $10=="$b"'
```

Moreover, I am running it in a while loop, so the `$a` and `$b` keep changing Please help..

Comment: wrt `I am running it in a while loop` - using a shell loop just to manipulate text is always the wrong approach. The end result is invariably lengthy, awkward, fragile, error prone, slow and generally bad software since that is not what shell is for. You might want to ask for help with that part of the bigger script in a separate question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are passing the shell variables to the awk command using a wrong method. It should be like

```
awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" '$1==a && $10 == b'
```

**What it does**

- `-v a="$a"` creates an awk variable `a` and assigns the value of shell variable `$a` to it.
- `-v b="$b"` Creates awk variable `b`.

**OR**

```
awk '$1==a && $10 == b' a="$a" b="$b" file
```

---

When you write a statement like this

```
awk -v '$1==$a' && '$10==$b' test_file
```

awk doesn't know what `$a` `$b` is because both are shell variables.

And the correct method of using `-v` for passing shell variables is as in demonstrated in the examples.

From awk manuals

> ```
> -v var=val
>
>    --assign var=val
>
>     Assign  the  value  val to the variable var, before execution of
>     the program begins.  Such variable values are available  to  the
>     BEGIN block of an AWK program.
> ```

---

**Test**

```
$ cat file 
2607s1  NC_000067.6 95.92   49  1   1   3   50  1e-14   84.2
2607s1  NC_000067.6 97.73   44  1   0   7   50  4e-14   84.2
2607s1  NC_000067.6 97.67   43  1   0   8   50  1e-13   75.0

$ a="2607s1"; b="84.2"

$ awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" '$1==a && $10 == b' file 
2607s1  NC_000067.6 95.92   49  1   1   3   50  1e-14   84.2
2607s1  NC_000067.6 97.73   44  1   0   7   50  4e-14   84.2
```

Comment: it works!, is it possible not to use the -v flag in this case?

Comment: @once I afraid not :( It is the only method of passing shell variables onto the awk script.

Comment: It isn't the only way, although it is the best. You can also do `awk '$1==a && $10 == b'  a="$a" b="$b" file`

Comment: @User112638726 Ooch I really missed that. Will add to answer. Thank you

Comment: Yeah there is another method as well. I missed it in the first place. see the updated answer or comment by @User112638726

Comment: You can also use `ENVIRON["a"]` but again `-v` is usually the right approach. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24. I personally find `"a=$a"` a very odd-looking syntax vs `a="$a"` but I expect it will work.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this (this avoids using -v parameters)

`awk '$1=="'$a'" && $10=="'$b'"' file`

The quote `'` just before `$a` will turn off string interpretation.

The quote `'` just after `$a` will turn on string interpretation.

`$a` is in this way interpreted and replaced by its value.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the below awk command.

```
awk -v var1="$a" -v var2="$b" '$1==var1&&$NF==var2' file
```